# Creating a child object in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance

I created a class model using Entity Framework 4, based on my (empty) database, and followed [this tutorial](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-type-inheritance/) to set up a table per type inheritance, with the `Student` and `Professor` inheriting the abstract `Person` class.

Everything worked fine and then I went ahead and created the `Student` controller and the generated code for creating students isn't working. I don't have access to my code now, so I can't paste it, but the `Create` function is something like this:

```
function create(Student student){
    db.person.AddObject(student);
    db.person.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is giving me an error saying the `Student` can't be added because there's no `Person` in the database with a corresponding key. I'm very new to asp.net, but I believe the database context isn't inserting a person before trying to insert into the student table.

I'm sorry I can't provide more details like pics of the DB design or the actual code, but this is the best I can do right now.

Thanks!

Comment: post you code, without it it is just guessing

Comment: @vittore I know it's not enough and I wish I could provide more information but I don't have access to the code right now. Nevertheless, I'm pretty sure the excerpt I posted is the code scaffolded when I created the Student controller (I've looked at it for so many hours it's burned in my retina)

Comment: how this create function is called , what is `student` ? is it data from the form?

Comment: When the StudentController is created, it generates the overloaded `Create` method, that receives a `Student` object from the form, by HTTP `post`. The view has a form with all the attributes of `Student` (inherited and specific). When the form is submitted, the controller uses this data to create a `Student` object and passes it to the `create` method up there. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

look now

```
datacontext    mainTable   subTable   what is needed to do.

   "db"     .  "person"  . "student" . blablabla
```

db as far as i understand is ur database context and person is ur table and you are calling a sub table "student" which needs to have a relation with "person". so in ur database make sure you got a key for your "person" and "student" tables and make sure u got a relation between them.

if u can give more info i can help further but right now based on ur information this is the only knowledge i can share..